# Fit image material in CesiumJS irregular rectangles (polygons)

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I am having some trouble working with the image material. I have entities that are irregular rectangles (polygons with 4 positions) and would like the image material to distort to always fit the space.

```
            let viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');

            viewer.entities.add(new Cesium.Entity({
            polygon:
            {
                hierarchy: 
                {
                    positions: [{ x: -5099561.112354739, y: 471018.36210765265, z: -3788996.464597908 },
                                { x: -5099564.409358333, y: 470982.66516832606, z: -3788996.4645979083 }, 
                                { x: -5099581.806381637, y: 470984.2719126955, z: -3788973.0084019853 }, 
                                { x: -5099578.5093667945, y: 471019.9689738013, z: -3788973.0084019853 }]
                },
                material: "https://images2.minutemediacdn.com/image/upload/c_crop,h_1414,w_2101,x_20,y_0/v1565279671/shape/mentalfloss/578211-gettyimages-542930526.jpg?itok=Nj49PDxW",
                stRotation: Cesium.Math.toRadians(45),
             }
        }));
```

[Cesium Sandcastle](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/index.html#c=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)

In the example the cat image appears cropped out of the polygon when I would like it to distort to fit within the polygon.

Comment: This example does show the cat image for me, although the camera isn't zoomed in nearly close enough to see it when the sample starts, I had to zoom in manually.  What do you see, and what are you expecting to see?

Comment: @emackey the image doesn't distort to fit the polygon. It gets cropped out. The expected result is I see the full cat image within that polygon. (I will amend to question to make it clearer sorry)